# Can I use local notifications in this case for my react-native app?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, aws-amplify

I have a food delivery app built with expo in react native and AWS amplify backend and in my app I want to notify my users when there order is ready. When the order is ready I update the status of the order object in the backend to 'ready' using the restaurant app and in the user app I have subscribed to the order data model thereby inside the user app in real time it shows that the order is ready. But how to fire a notification in the user side app when order is ready which even works when the app is closed. Can I use local notifications for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send local notification in react-native in expo cli using expo notification
checkout this link :-
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Comment: Will the notifications work even when the app is closed?

Comment: yes, but there is some configuration for that in IOS and android @hewa